# Tool to proxy AWS Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services

So, I'm looking for something I swear I already have but can't find.  I've also Google'd extensively, and really can't find it -- I know I've used it before.

The tool I'm looking for is a local proxy to AWS.  I think it was written in Python, but not sure.  Essentially, you just start this local process with your AWS credentials, and it works like a proxy for REST requests.  You can make a request to it (a port on localhost), and it signs the request and sends it on to AWS, and then returns the results.

So you can really do something like:

```
$ sometool AWSKEY=foo AWSSECRET=bar &
>> open port on localhost:3333
$ curl -d 'somecontent' localhost:3333
```

it's more complicated than that, but that's the idea.  Anyone know the tool I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [ec2-api-proxy](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/ec2-api-proxy). Its a python based proxy server which caches api results in memcached.